# how to split values in XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: ajax, xml, linq-to-xml

i have xmlhttpRequest for searching in the list of cours 
on of my function is for search by program... but some cours have more then one program so i would like to be able to write the number of just one program and find all the cours they have this program even of the cours have other program

here is a part of my xml file
when i write 4108 in my input text i would like to output the cours which contain this number

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<tousCours>
  <cours>
   <sigle>GEN0103</sigle>
   <titre>Chimie générale</titre>
   <prgs>
  <pr>0000</pr>
</prgs>
<credits>3</credits>
</cours>
<cours>
<sigle>GEN0123</sigle>
<titre>Physique mécanique et optique</titre>
<prgs>
  <pr>0000</pr>
</prgs>
<credits>3</credits>
</cours>
<cours>
<sigle>GEN1002</sigle>
<titre>Ingénierie et éthique</titre>
<prgs>
  <pr>7643</pr>
</prgs>
<prealable>GEN1000, GEN1001</prealable>
<credits>2</credits>
</cours>
<cours>
<sigle>GEN1023</sigle>
<titre>Matériaux I</titre>
<prgs>
  <pr>7643</pr>
</prgs>
<credits>3</credits>
</cours>
<cours>
<sigle>GEN1033</sigle>
<titre>Statique</titre>
<prgs>
  <pr>7643</pr>
</prgs>
<credits>3</credits>
</cours>
<cours>
<sigle>GEN1041</sigle>
<titre>Ingénierie et entreprises</titre>
<prgs>
  <pr>7643</pr>
</prgs>
<credits>3</credits>
</cours>
 <cours>
<sigle>GEN1051</sigle>
<titre>Ingénierie et entreprises II</titre>
<prgs>
  <pr>4108</pr>
  <pr>7643</pr>
  <pr>7833</pr>
</prgs>
<credits>3</credits>
</cours>
```

here is my xmlhttprequest

```
 xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 function rechercherProg() {
        var texte2 = document.getElementById("prog").value; 
        xhttp.open("GET", "WebForm3.aspx/?prog=" + texte2 + "substring-after(',')", false);
        xhttp.send();
        Afficher(xhttp.responseXML);
    }
```

and here is my code of server side (linq to xml)

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
</head>
 <body>
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
  var text = Request.Params[0];

             XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("~/cours.xml"));
             XDocument xresp = new XDocument(new XElement("tousCours"));

             if (text != "")
             {
                 IEnumerable<XElement> prog =
                     from b in xdoc.Elements("tousCours").Elements("cours")
                     where (string)b.Element("prgs/pr") == text 
                     select b;
                 foreach (XElement xEle in prog)
                     xresp.Element("tousCours").Add(xEle);
             }
             Response.Clear();
             Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
             Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
             xresp.Save(Response.Output);
             Response.End();
```

here is my table
[image: my table]

i have a full table with all my cours and i want the result of what i search to appear on the other table

like this one

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of `where (string)b.Element("prgs/pr") == text` you want

```
 where b.Element("prgs").Elements("pr").Any(pr => (string)pr == text)
```

If you not only want to select and return elements from the existing document but also want to reduce the `pr` element to the value looked for then use e.g.

```
         if (text != "")
         {
             xresp.Root.Add(
                 from b in doc.Elements("tousCours").Elements("cours")
                 where b.Element("prgs").Elements("pr").Any(pr => (string)pr == text)
                 select new XElement(b.Name,
                                    b.Elements().Except(b.Elements("prgs")),
                                    new XElement("prgs",
                                                new XElement("pr", text))));
         }
```

This still looks up the elements the same way as already suggested but constructs new content eliminating any `pr` elements that are different from the `text` value so that instead of e.g.

```
<cours>
<sigle>GEN1051</sigle>
<titre>Ingénierie et entreprises II</titre>
<prgs>
  <pr>4108</pr>
  <pr>7643</pr>
  <pr>7833</pr>
</prgs>
<credits>3</credits>
</cours>
```

the code returns solely

```
<tousCours>
  <cours>
    <sigle>GEN1051</sigle>
    <titre>Ingénierie et entreprises II</titre>
    <credits>3</credits>
    <prgs>
      <pr>4108</pr>
    </prgs>
  </cours>
</tousCours>
```

Comment: thank you its a bit better now, its return me a result but is void... that just return me the head of my table without response in...

Comment: Can you show us a minimal but complete XML samples, including any XML namespace declarations (e.g. `xmlns="..."`) that might exist?

Comment: As far as I can tell, the LINQ to XML query is correct for that XML you posted. I am not sure what the `"WebForm3.aspx/?prog=" + texte2 + "substring-after(',')"` is about, if you have these numbers like `4108` in the text input then I would simply expect you to use ``"WebForm3.aspx/?prog=" + texte2`. Or do you want users to enter a list of numbers in that input? But `substring-after(',')` seems like XPath and I am not sure what it is supposed to achieve in the query string you assemble in client-side Javascript.

Comment: because in my table i have something like that 4108,7643,7833 and if user write 4108 i want output sigle: GEN1051
titre :Ingénierie et entreprises II
 pr :4108
  credit:3

Comment: Perhaps split that question into several, one for the client-side stuff, one for the LINQ query, one for the the ASP.NET code. I am currently not sure what kind of "table" you refer to, in any case, if that HTML `input` element contains a single number then I think you should pass it as `"WebForm3.aspx/?prog=" + texte2` and the LINQ suggestion I made should select and return any elements containing that value in the `pr` children of the `prgs` element.

Comment: thank you! i add picture of my table, maybe it could help :)

Comment: im very sorry you was right!!! its work well what you suggest me!!!! im sorry i dont know why i thought its didn't work... i think i forget to refresh my browser before test the code...